# Whole word matching with unexpected insertion in data

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I have string consider

```
my $string = 'String need to be evaluated';
```

in `$string` I'm searching evaluated or any other word.
problem is their may be insertion of some tags in string
eg. `Str<data>ing need to be eval<data>ua<data>ted` which is unexpected.
In this case how could I search for the words?

here is the code I tried:

```
my $string = 'Text to be evaluated';

my $string2 = "Te<data>xt need to be eval<data2>ua<data>ted";
# patten to match
$pattern = "evaluated";

@b = split('',$pattern);

for my $i(@b){
    $i="$i"."\(?:<data>\)?";
    print "$i#\n";
}
$pattern = join('',@b);

print "\n$pattern\n";

if ($string2 =~ /$pattern/){
    print "$pattern found\n";   
}
```

Do you suggest any other method or module to make it easy? i don't know what kind of data will get inserted.

Comment: Remove the tags first, then search?

Comment: No the tags have important information. The search must handle any unexpected insertion

Comment: So, remove tags on copy of the string?

Comment: @mpapec I'm processing this in substitution on a single varible which needs to be processed further. I have to do everything on that single varible.

Comment: Why can't you use a copy? Might new tags be inserted during the runtime of this sub by some other thread? Or is it just about conserving the tags?

Comment: @DeVadder It is just about conserving tag.

Comment: Well, then you can just copy the string, remove the tags on the copy, match it, and if it does, you know that the original string had the pattern...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you need but how about

```
@b = split('',$pattern);

for my $i(@b){
    $i=$i.".*";
    print "$i \n";
}
$pattern = join('',@b);
```

That should match any string that had the pattern before it got random insertions as long as the characters of the pattern are still there and in the correct order.
It does find `evaluated` in the string `esouhgvw8vwrg355#*asrgl/\u[\w]atet(45)<data>efdvd` what is about as noisy as it gets. But of course, if it is impossible to distinguish between insertion and original string, you will get "false" positives. For example if the string used to be `evaluted` and it becomes something like `evalu<hereisyourmissinga>ted` you will get a positive. Of course, if you knew that insertions would always be in tags while text is not, users answer is much safer.

As long as you single quote your input string, characters like [\w] (45) and whatnot should not hurt either. I cannot see why they would be interpolated at any point.

Comment: `$i=$i.'.*?';` or `$i=$i.'[^ ]+';` can be better in this case. I just wanted to know is their any module available for this instance. Or any method or concept like schwatzian tranform or something...

Comment: Every improvement would require more (any) knowledge about the form of insertions. With your second suggestion you assume insertions to not contain spaces. And non-greediness should not change the outcome of the question "match or no match" at all as both greediness and non-greediness try to match the longest/shortest sub-string that still allows the rest of the pattern to match. But for substitutions it should be better indeed.

Comment: @wagh As to Schwartz Transform and similar: I personally do not care for stuff that only improves time efficiency in Perl. If your task is time-limited on the machine it is supposed to run on, do not use Perl. Or any scripting language. I love Perl but for the ease of use and readability (if written to be readable of course) and not for its performance. Use something closer to the underlying system for that. In my case C++.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could use regexp to do the job:

```
foreach my  $s ($string,$string2){
   my $cs= $s;
   ### canonize
   $cs =~ s!<[^>]*>!!gs;
   ### match
   if ($cs =~ m!$pattern!i){
      print "Found $pattern in $s!\n";
   }        
}
```

Comment: But the Op explicitly does not want to remove the tags. It is not clear why, but that seems to be a requirement.

Comment: i have changed the script but If this small change is not obivous for you then please read. There are lot of good books about how to programm with Perl.

Comment: Thank you very much, luckily i can in fact read. And yes, that is obviously a practical answer. But the Op had stated in the comments explicitly that he did not want to remove the tags, be it in a copy or not. Of course it is not really clear why he does not want to make a copy, remove the tags in that copy and match against that copy, but it had been suggested and he had said that that was not what he needed. No idea why, only reason i could imagine would be obscenely huge strings but who knows.

Comment: @DeVadder I can't tell what kind of insertion it will have.Insertion can be other than tags. that's why  I requires a solution to match in that string alone because copying $string will make no sense in that case. my approach given in code is somewhat near to the solution but it can't handle everything like insertion of parenthesis data or [\w+], {\w+} or anything else.

Comment: @wagh - The words are the signals; the 'insertions' are the noise.  To get the signals, i.e., recognize the words, you must recognize and remove the noise.  What, specifically, distinguishes the 'insertions' from the words in which they occur?  If you can't say what the noise is--what the 'insertions' are--how can you find the words?

Comment: @Kenosis Thats why I'm stuck at this problem. Can I use the approach of text compare tools?