# adding pattern within the string in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want to append particular pattern between each character in a word and then that word+pattern I want to match that against filecontent.

I am able to append pattern but while matching it takes a lot time.. especially when appending pattern like **‘\s*’** or **‘\n’**

suppose a word is 'accomodation'

then after adding pattern to it it becomes

```
a(?:(?:<tag>|\n)+)?c(?:(?:<tag>|\n)+)?c(?:(?:<tag>|\n)+)?o(?:(?:<tag>|\n)+)?m(?:(?:<tag>|\n)+)?o(?:(?:<tag>|\n)+)?d(?:(?:<tag>|\n)+)?a(?:(?:<tag>|\n)+)?t(?:(?:<tag>|\n)+)?i(?:(?:<tag>|\n)+)?o(?:(?:<tag>|\n)+)?n
```

while matching the above pattern against $filecontent..it takes alot of time..please suggest some other alternative

**EXAMPLE 2:**

```
$string1 = "perl is not <match>frequently used</match> for web development";
$string2 = "perl is not fr<sc>e</sc>
qu<abctag>en<abctag>
tly used<abctag> for web development";
```

output required:

```
perl is not <match>fr<sc>e</sc>
qu<abctag>en<abctag>
tly used</match><abctag> for web development
```

Comment: when i am removing \s or \n it takes lesser time but some instances does not match

Comment: That hardly sounds like the actual requirement. Why are you doing that? Are you trying to match your word against `$filecontent` but also (only?) want it to match when there are `\s` or `\n` between any two characters or what is the purpose? If you are looking for a faster solution to your underlying problem, state that problem as well as your attempt.

Comment: @DeVadder Pls check i have edited the above with example 2

Comment: I still do not get it. This time you had two different things that got added. Is everything okay that is a `<tag>`? Or only individual ones? Maybe your problem is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401964/whole-word-matching-with-unexpected-insertion-in-data/21425700#21425700

Comment: @DeVadder yes its similar but while matching with large text..appending the pattern to each character and then matching it cause my program keeps on running...

Comment: @DeVadder when i want to match text like `perl is scripting language` then after appending a pattern that text looks like `p<pat>e<pat>r<pat>l<pat> i<pat>s <pat>s<pat>c<pat>r<pat>i<pat>p<pat>t<pat>i<pat>n<pat>g l<pat>a<pat>n<pat>g<pat>u<pat>a<pat>g<pat>e<pat>` then matching these large string causes a problem

Comment: @ruakh ??????????????

Comment: @vivekpro: Sorry, I just now saw your comment, and only by chance. Note that you can't tag random people in a comment; you can only tag someone who's posted in the thread you're commenting on. (I posted an answer, but that only means I'm not notified of comments to the answer, not comments to the question.) But it's just as well, because I don't understand your comment anyway. I haven't posted in this thread, so how can I have inspired a "??????????????"?

Answer (score 0):

`(?:(?:...)+)?` is a bit more verbose than is needed; you can just write `(?:...)*`. (`+` means "one or more", `?` means "zero or one", `*` means "zero or more".)

But the actual problem is that your regex invites a huge amount of backtracking; you can probably improve performance significantly by wrapping your repetitions in `(?>...)`, which disables backtracking. (In some cases this can affect the semantics of the regex, but in your example it will only affect the performance.)

That would look like this:

```
a(?>(?:<tag>|\n)*)c(?>(?:<tag>|\n)*)c(?>(?:<tag>|\n)*)o(?>(?:<tag>|\n)*)m(?>(?:<tag>|\n)*)o(?>(?:<tag>|\n)*)d(?>(?:<tag>|\n)*)a(?>(?:<tag>|\n)*)t(?>(?:<tag>|\n)*)i(?>(?:<tag>|\n)*)o(?>(?:<tag>|\n)*)n
```

Answer (score 0):

I am *still* not sure what the problem is but i will try anyways. I assume the actual question is as follows:
You have a string that you want to find in a large file. But within that file, the string might have inserted tags. So lets say you look for `matchingString`, then you also want the pattern to find `m<bla>atching<blub>Strin<whatever>g`.
Because there is no information about that, i will assume, that the tags are "in order". That is every `<` is followed by some text not part of the original string (but not `<` ) followed by a `>` after which the original string resumes.
So there is nothing like `match<outer<inner>>ingString`.

```
my $pattern = "match";
my @b = split('',$pattern);
$pattern = join('(?><[^>]*?>)*',@b);
```

This should result in a pattern finding those strings and i cannot think of a faster way to do it.

```
m(?><[^>]*?>)*a(?><[^>]*?>)*t(?><[^>]*?>)*c(?><[^>]*?>)*h
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IUJsWJCDusOdEBU5)

Comment: i have two files html and xml file as input. the text to be match is present in html file and it is between the tags `<match>` and `</match>`. Now, these texts is to be searched in xml file and we have to insert tag `<matched>` and `<matched>` in xml. problem is the xml file have **newlines** and **tags** (i.e <xmltag>) in it. so i tried to add pattern `(?:(?:\n|<xmltag>)+)?` but it works on just few files.. and on other file its keep on running.. Please suggest

Comment: Is it always literal `<xmltag>` or do you mean it are tags of the xml format? Either way, try replacing the pattern i put in my answer with '(?>(?:<[^>]*?>)|\n)*'. Of course that is almost the exact same thing that ruakh posted, except that this one takes tags with any text in them. That is assuming the text in tags neither contains other tags nor \n.

Comment: i have large data(i.e 2-3 lines) to be match from html to xml. but these data in xml have newlines and tag.

Comment: Did you try the regex i posted? It should not bother about newlines as long as they are not within tags like `<\n>`.

Comment: suppose text from html to be matched is **perl is &#x0000; developed for web application** and these in xml **p<xmltag>erl i<xmltag>s &#x0123; devel<xmltag>oped for web app<xmltag>lication**...see unicode value may changed so in final output we have to retain data which is given in xml file. so im am converting unicode from html to `<unicode;1>` and so on ... while splitting these text, pattern is used split /(&#x\w+;)|/,$text;.. i am getting an array which have each character and unicode value in each element of array then appending my pat..

Comment: Sorry, i guess i cannot help you. If you append the pattern i posted after every character of the original string you are looking for, it will match a version of that string with randomly inserted tags and newlines. That was the question and in your example it easily finds string1 in string2. That is all i can do for you. I have no idea what you want with unicode all of a sudden. I suggest you ask a new question including all the information about what you are trying to do and what the caveats are *from the beginning* instead of piece by piece. As is, this was a waste of both our time.

Comment: Questions are allowed to have more characters than comments. Use them. Give example code, example input, *actual* example input that is, including the problem cases, and desired output. And explain how the input is supposed to become the output.