# How to match thing that is not in capture buffer in perl

Tags: regex, perl

Here is the sample script with my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $string = "aaabc";

my $re = qr/
    ^           # Start of line
    (.)         # Now \1 has 'a'
    .*?         #
    ([^\1])     # This is incorrect. It does not work as I need
                # Here I need to match the thing that is not \1
                # (in this case I need to match 'b')
/x;

if ($string =~ $re) {

    say $1;
    say $2;

} else {

    say 'no match';

}
```

Comment: Use a negative [look-ahead assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions). `(?!\1)` will match a string that is not `\1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a Negative Lookahead. This will find the pattern and start the rest of the search from there. Meaning the next capture will be the one you seek.

```
my $re = qr/
    ^              # Start of line
    (.)            # Now \1 has 'a'
     .*?           #    also (.)+? works as first expression.
    (?!\1)         # Negative Lookahead is non-capturing
    (.)            # $2 is b
/x;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exaclty what I was looking for.

Comment: And here is the link to the doc about `(?!pattern)` http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?!pattern%29

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [@DeVadder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2885683/devadder), you could make use of [`(?>pattern)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?%3Epattern%29) which is:

> an "independent" subexpression, one which matches the substring that a
>   standalone pattern would match if anchored at the given position, and
>   it matches nothing other than this substring.

```
my $re = qr/
    ^           # Start of line
    (.)         # Now \1 has 'a'
    (?>\1*)     # Matches \1
    (.)
/x;
```

This would handle both cases *as expected*.

Comment: Thank you. But this is not the solution. For the string 'aaa' it will match 'a' and 'a', but for me the 'no match' is needed.

Comment: If you want to stick with the 'not negative lookahead' answer, you could use `(?>\1*)` instead of just `\1*` in the original answer. That is a greedy, give nothing back group. So it matches as much a as it can find and refuses to give any back to the remaining part of the regex. So aaa would indeed not match the complete regex. I suppose that would solve the problem and be a lot faster than lookahead, for what it's worth.

Comment: @DeVadder Thanks for introducing me to http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?%3Epattern%29

Comment: @devnull ^^ I also just learned about it yesterday by an answer of ruakh here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22165616/2885683

Comment: Thank you! I've decided to use @doncoyote's answer `(?!\1)` insted of your `(?>\1*)`. There is much less text for it in help http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?!pattern%29 and it's easier to understand than http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28?%3Epattern%29

Comment: @bessarabov Personally i would also argue that knowing and understanding lookahead and lookbehind might prove a lot more useful in other situations. This is just a neat special case where the non-backtracking-ness of (?>) can be employed.

Answer (score 1):

The regex searches captures first character and use it as \1*. Finally get a character that might be same as \1 or different if exists and check if $1 and $2 are same. If they are same then there is no character other than $1. If we have a character then we have a match and $1 ne $2.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use feature 'say';

while(<DATA>){
    my $re = qr/^(.)\1*(.)/x;
    if ($_=~$re && $1 ne $2) {
    say $1;
    say $2;

    } else {
    say 'no match';
    }
}

__DATA__
aaaa
aaabc
abc
baacd
```

Output :

```
   no match
    a
    b
    a
    b
    b
    a
```